# Basic for() loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm new to loops and R in general.  Using the "iris" datasets I need to use a for() loop and create an object called 'X.IQR' that contains the interquartile range of each of the first four columns of "iris".  Could someone please provide a little insight for me here? Thank you!

Edit: Sorry forgot to include my attempts

```
for(row in 1:150){
for(column in 1:4){
print(paste("row =",row,"; col =",column))
print(iris[1:150,1:4])
}
}
```

I've tried this code here which is partially my knowledge and partially example code that I have learned in my class.  I understand that this is a loop and I THINK that I have specified the first 4 columns as I desire I'm just not sure how to incorporate IQR here, anyone have any advice?

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: My insight would be to not use a `for()` loop. Instead read `help(IQR)` and then `help(sapply)`.

Comment: A solution similar to the one posted below, based on the comment by @RichardScriven, could be `X.IQR <- sapply(seq(4), function(x) IQR(iris[,x]))`

Answer (score 3):

When selecting a subset of the data if you intend to have all the rows, as you have, you can just omit the row selection:

```
iris[1:150,1:4]
```

becomes

```
iris[ ,1:4]
```

as Richard mentioned in a comment, you can use sapply:

```
X.IQR = sapply(X = iris[,1:4], FUN = IQR)
```

`sapply` will apply the `FUN` (function) `IQR` to each element of the iris dataset, which corresponds to its columns.

or using apply:

```
X.IQR = apply(X = iris[ ,1:4], 2, FUN = IQR)
```

`apply` can do the same thing, but its a bit more code and won't always be as clean.

Read more with the excellent response here: [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)

Comment: What do you mean by "won't always be as clean"?

Comment: It will coerce to a matrix if it was operating on a data.frame.

Comment: A matrix is not dirty as well.

Comment: I understand how to use the apply function but I specifically would like to know how to use a for-loop just to gain experience.